# Swapping list with index

Tags: python, list, swap

Just want to ask how do i swap the list at the index with the list that follows it and if the list at the index is on the bottom, swap that with the top.
So that the index would swap places with the position the list is with the next number For example Normal = [1,2,3,4] and index of 1 would turn to = [1, 3, 2, 4]. making the 2 and 3 swap places and index of 3 would make [4, 2, 3, 1]

Comment: can you describe the procedure of swapping the example list in detail

Comment: Normal = [1,2,3,4] and index of 1 would turn to mutated = [1, 3, 2, 4]
swapping the index with the following number

Comment: @itachi123 pls edit your question and add the additional information there. (and not in comments)

Answer (score 0):

```
def swap(lst, swap_index):
    try:
        next_index = (swap_index + 1) % len(lst)
        lst[swap_index], lst[next_index] = lst[next_index], lst[swap_index]
    except IndexError:
        print "index out of range"
lst = [1,2,3,4]
swap_index = 4
swap(lst,swap_index)
print lst
```

pay attention that everything in Python is reference, that is to say, the `swap` function swap elements in place

Answer (score 0):

I threw together a quick function which should work with any values, though Hootings way may be better.

```
def itatchi_swap(x, n):
    x_len = len(x)
    if not 0 <= n < x_len:
        return x
    elif n == x_len - 1:
        return [x[-1]] + x[1:-1] + [x[0]]
    else:
        return x[:n] + [x[n+1]] + [x[n]] + x[n+2:]
```

And slightly modified to mutate the list:

```
def itatchi_swap(x, n):
    x_len = len(x)
    if 0 <= n < x_len:
        if n == x_len - 1:
            v = x[0]
            x[0] = x[-1]
            x[-1] = v
        else:
            v = x[n]
            x[n] = x[n+1]
            x[n+1] = v
```

Comment: how do i make it so its just mutable like it doesn't return anything just mutating it and would work with any length of the list like even a list of 20 number would work

Comment: As to the question, it should do, and as to the first bit, I'll have to have a play around tomorrow, not quite sure how to do that with lists :P

Comment: Updated so it doesn't return anything