# how to swap item in a list of Python

Tags: python

So I have a problem, I want to swap two item in a list given there index of the first integer we will swap it with the integer that follows it. How can I do this, So here is an example: swap[1,2,3,4], index = 0; result = [2,1,3,4]

Comment: `your_list[index], your_list[index + 1] = your_list[index + 1], your_list[index]`

Comment: I tried using that but the problem I'm having is that it doesn't add to the list and it prints that old list

Comment: Is this a question from some sort of assignment? This [very same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707997/swapping-list-with-index) has been asked here several times the last couple hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list=[1,2,3,4]
i=0  #your index 
if i==(len(list)-1):
   j=0
else:
   j=i+1
list[i], list[j] = list[j], list[i]
```

if you are not sure of the index and want to swap by a specific value on the list use `i=list.index("2")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer really helps

Comment: @SyedNaqi glad I could help

Comment: Also I just have one more concern If the index is that of the last position like the last element I want to swap it with the first element in the list how can I do that so for ex: my_list = [1,2,3,4] index = 3 result = [4,2,3,1] can you tell me how can I do that.

Comment: @SyedNaqi edited my answer

Comment: It shows syntax error when you do if (i==(len(list)-1):

Comment: @SyedNaqi oh sorry, not ( before i

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: can you please tell me how to do this

Comment: @SyedNaqi works fine for me

Comment: so should I add a bracket before the list

Comment: it works but instead of swapping the first and last element is swaps the other elements

Comment: @SyedNaqi observe carefully, it seems perfectly fine on my laptop

Comment: does it swap the first and the last item

Comment: @SyedNaqi yes it does, I don't know what's wrong